# How to get vertical space under footer in Madrid theme of beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

How to get vertical space "\vspace{1cm}" under footer in Madrid theme of Beamer.
This is what I have tried, but I am unsuccessful.

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertsection
    \end{beamercolorbox}%

    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertsubsection
    \end{beamercolorbox}%

    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
\vspace{1cm}%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append a bit of vertical space to the template like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{\vskip0.5cm}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]